# Could someone write a program that print the exactly code of the program. Only use print('')

Tags: python

Only use `print("")` to write this code.

Write a program that prints out the requested information above, similar to below:

```
My Name:       Jason Newton
Element:       Carbonated Soda-type
Target Number: 7
Hobby:         Video Gaming
```

Comment: So you haven't even try to copy each line and pass directly to `print()`? Well-deserved downvote.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Answer (score 2):

just take the answer:

```
print("""\
My Name:       Jason Newton
Element:       Carbonated Soda-type
Target Number: 7
Hobby:         Video Gaming""")
```

Comment: That was hard, but you managed to answer with code which produces wrong output.

Comment: it gives me the right output

Comment: You've edited it since I wrote previous comment, now it produces semi-correct output. What if my terminal uses non-monospace font?

Comment: idk i have not a terminal with non-monospace font

Comment: Just write four separate print statements like this `print("My Name:", "Jason Newton", sep="\t\t")`

Comment: whats the difference, mine uses docstrings but you could do it just type `print("My Name:\t\tJason Newton\nElement:\t\tCarbonated Soda-type\nTarget Number: 7\nHobby:\t\tVideo Gaming")
`

Comment: The difference is in tabulation, yes you can do it as you shown.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yours would likely misalign.